# Make sprites character faces topleft

Tags: actionscript-3

i already have this sprites on my computer (taken from internet), but how do i make it faces top left? because this sprites do not have character that faces topleft.. My question is, how do i do that? i want use this sprites character for my game, 2.5D..
Thanks.

[image]

I want it to faced like this (topleft):

[image]

I appreciate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: You can't , cause you don't have a chicken character in your spritesheet

Comment: i mean, the chicken character already faces top left (taken from internet). What i want is to make "Efis" sprite character to faces topleft like chicken sprite character did. How do i do that? I dont have a file of "Efis" sprite character, just the image only like the one that i posted

Comment: What engine you're using?

Comment: flash professional (for design) and flash develop (for coding).. Both of "Efis" character and "Chicken" character are taken from internet as image.

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to make the sprite face diagonally, somewhat up, and somewhat to the left?  (To me, it looks like the chicken is facing to the right, but it's hard for me to really make out individual features on the chicken.)

In that case, you probably really need to draw a new graphic that is based on the others.  Hire someone else, if you have to.  Stuff that's easy to do in a typical programming language would have to do more with moving graphics around (translation), flipping them, rotating them, stretching them, that kind of thing.  Those are the four basic geometric transformations in a programming language, and simply changing the alpha of the whole thing or something like that should be easy as well.  But it's not easy at all to programmatically create something that looks like a brand new graphic, even if it is sort of similar to some graphics you already you have.

Comment: so, what do you suggest is i don't have to rotate it by manually but automatically through code? so, i load the image which is "Efie" character where he facing to the front. And whenever i want the character to face the top left, what i must do is rotate it through code. Isn't it what you mean?

Comment: You need to draw the graphic from scratch.  If you were using 3D images and had all the necessary animations set up, then you could rotate him pretty easily.  But since you're working with 2D, and since the differences between up/down/left/right are more than simple rotations or something, you really need a new graphic, which needs to be done in some sort of Paint program.

Comment: so, i really cannot do anything with that sprites character (do the rotation), since i didn't have the file on me? Unless i have to draw again that sprites character from scratch, isn't it?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  I mean, you *could* programmatically just sort of put enough pixels together the right way, but it would take you a lot longer than to draw him again.  If you had a 3D model, then you could keep the basic overhead view and just rotate him via the other two axes (ultimately around the overhead axis, either y or z, depending on how you like to think about it); but this looks a lot like you're using a 2D model, which means the best way to handle it is to add either one or three more graphics to that spreadsheet you showed us, depending on whether he walks in that direction.